# got error when trying to use playground book template from apple

Tags: swift, swift-playground

i get this error:

/Users/.../Downloads/Swift_Playgrounds_Author_Template_for_Xcode_11.3/Template/PlaygroundBook/Modules/BookCore.playgroundmodule/Sources/LiveViewSupport.swift:9:8: Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.2 compiler: /Users/.../Downloads/Swift_Playgrounds_Author_Template_for_Xcode_11.3/Template/SupportingContent/PlaygroundsFrameworks/iphonesimulator/PlaygroundSupport.framework/Modules/PlaygroundSupport.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule

when i try to run the latest playground book template downloaded from Apple.

i already set the linker flag 
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES

for all libraries and the project itself -> didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` should be set on the framework being imported. Apple it seems did not update the framework and apply this setting. You should file a bug report.

This discussion happened on the forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126800